# ParamQuery ColModel not displaying correctly

Tags: struts2-jquery-grid, paramquery

I would like to request assistance to verify a behavior of ParamQuery Library, I am not sure what can be related to:

I am trying to implement a ColModel based on each week of the year, this ColModel is dinamic and will change based on the year since each week will have different dates per week, and each week will start on a different date.

I have successfully implemented a static colModel joined with the dynamic Model using one of the examples on the site.

The example used is the following: https://paramquery.com/demos/editing_instant

To this exact model I am attaching new columns based on selected dates using PHP. by using the following structure:

[image: ColModelArray]

This ColModel is properly designed using PHP, and it displays correctly most of the times (Please see attached).

[image: DataVisualization is correct]

However, when changing screen size or by scrolling trough the table, the headers will start to throttle and be displayed incorrectly:

[image: Column headers start to display incorrectly]

Does anyone know how to fix this?, or if it has to do with display properties?

PHP code to generate weeks and days:

```
$respuesta = array();
$semanaAct = 55;
$CambioSemana = 0;

$Fin = '2018-02-26';

$begin = new DateTime( '2018-02-01' );
$end = new DateTime( $Fin );
$Realend = new DateTime( $Fin );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 
//$begin = $begin->modify( '-1 day' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    $SemanaFecha = $date->format("W");
    if($SemanaFecha==$semanaAct){
        $dias[] = array("title" =>$date->format("d-m"),"week" => $date->format("W"));
        $semanaar["colModel"]= $dias;
        array_push($respuesta, "Day: ".$date->format("d-m"). " Week: ".$date->format("W") );
        $CambioSemana = 2;
    }
    else{
        if($CambioSemana == 2){
            array_push($rows, $semanaar);
        }
        $semanaAct = $date->format("W");
        $semanaar= ["title"=> "Week ".$semanaAct, "dataType"=> "string","colModel"=> ""];
        $ContadorSemanas++;

        $dias = array();
        $dias[] = array("title" =>$date->format("d-m"),"week" => $date->format("W"));
        $semanaar["colModel"]= $dias;
        $CambioSemana = 1;
    }

    if( $date->format("d-m") == $Realend->format("d-m") ){
        array_push($respuesta, "Final 11");
        array_push($rows, $semanaar);
    }
    //array_push($respuesta, "Semana: ".$SemanaFecha);

}
return "[{\"columns\":".json_encode($GLOBALS['rows']). "}]";
```

Once the ColModel is generated, the table is refreshed using the following:

```
    var obj1 = $.parseJSON(result);
    //console.log(obj1);
    var columns = obj1[0].columns;
    $("#grid_editing").pqGrid( "option" , "colModel", colModelTemp );
    $grid.pqGrid( 'refresh' );
```

Comment: Please, correct your tag - you use pqGrid, but your tag is jqGrid - that are quite different products

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the VirtualX property on JavaScript, by removing this option the scroll works perfectly.